# Donut chart: show percentage inside

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

In my project I am using d3.js to create a donut chart. On page load, the portion of the chart corresponds to the first data will highlighted. On clicking on each section it will be highlighted accordingly. It works fine for me up to now. The requirement is to show the percentage of currently selected portion in the center of the chart like below.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> D3 Js Example </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js" ></script>
    <script>

        var lastSelected = "";
var firstSelected = "";

var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

var normalArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 30).innerRadius(radius - 70);
var biggerArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 80).innerRadius(radius - 10);

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"])

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

  
svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', normalArc)
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .attr('d', function(d, index) {
        // If this is the first segment make it a wider arc
        if (index === 0) {
            firstSelected = this;
            return biggerArc(d);
        } else {
            return normalArc(d);
        }
    }).on("click", function(d) {
        if (firstSelected) {
            d3.select(firstSelected).attr("d", normalArc)
            firstSelected = false;
        }
        if (lastSelected) {
            d3.select(lastSelected).attr("d", normalArc)
        }
        d3.select(this).attr("d", biggerArc)
        lastSelected = this;
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the total in your data:

```
var total = d3.sum(d3.values(data));
```

Set up a text selection:

```
var centralText = svg.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Finally, pass the formatted value to that selection:

```
centralText.text(d3.format(".0%")(d.value / total));
```

Here is your updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> D3 Js Example </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var lastSelected = "";
      var firstSelected = "";

      var width = 450
      height = 450
      margin = 40

      var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

      var normalArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 30).innerRadius(radius - 70);
      var biggerArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 80).innerRadius(radius - 10);

      var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

      var data = {
        a: 9,
        b: 20,
        c: 30,
        d: 8,
        e: 12
      };

      var total = d3.sum(d3.values(data));

      var centralText = svg.append("text")
        .attr("font-size", "28px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(d3.format(".0%")(data.a / total));

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(data)
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"])

      var pie = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })
      var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))


      svg
        .selectAll('whatever')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', normalArc)
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
          return (color(d.data.key))
        })
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .style("opacity", 0.7)
        .attr('d', function(d, index) {
          // If this is the first segment make it a wider arc
          if (index === 0) {
            firstSelected = this;
            return biggerArc(d);
          } else {
            return normalArc(d);
          }
        }).on("click", function(d) {
          centralText.text(d3.format(".0%")(d.value / total))
          if (firstSelected) {
            d3.select(firstSelected).attr("d", normalArc)
            firstSelected = false;
          }
          if (lastSelected) {
            d3.select(lastSelected).attr("d", normalArc)
          }
          d3.select(this).attr("d", biggerArc)
          lastSelected = this;
        })

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```